# Access Google Drive with PHP (or javascript)

Tags: php, google-drive-api, authorization

I have a small site/web application where registered users can see some files that I periodically prepare for them; I store these files in separate directories and every user can only see and download their own files. 
Now, I'm moving these directories to Google Drive and I would keep functionalities like file listing and downloading.

Reading the official docs I found some interesting examples about file download/upload, but all of them talk about authorization that user must give in order to access to their Drive and this is not what I'm looking for, I don't want access to their Drive!

As I can see, the doc is not contempling the case that someone may want to give (read-only) access to own Drive. But maybe I'm missing something...

Basically, I need the list of files on my Drive account and, if requested, a way to download one (or more). The only one that has the auth to Drive account is my server, users will send request from it.

Is it possible? I think yes, but I can't find any docs about that. How can I authorize my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app) where you'll be using [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts) to achieve your goal.

> "This document explains how web server applications use the Google API
>   Client Library for PHP to implement OAuth 2.0 authorization to access
>   Google APIs. OAuth 2.0 allows users to share specific data with an
>   application while keeping their usernames, passwords, and other
>   information private. For example, an application can use OAuth 2.0 to
>   obtain permission from users to store files in their Google Drives."

The snippets are in PHP too, so it works in your favor.

Comment: Thanks, it should be what I was looking for!